# Javascript mark first letter in alphabetical array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a array with names sort alphabetical.
Andy
Albert
Andrea
Bert
Bernhard
Danniel

Now i need to mark the first name  that matches to A-Z
**Andy**
Albert
Andrea
**Bert**
Bernard
**Daniel**

Any ideas?

```
<li class="first">Andy</li>
<li class="second">Andrea</li>
<li class="second">Albert</li>
<li class="first">Bernard</li>
<li class="second">Bert</li>
```

it's a large array. At the moment all have class="second".
I wanna only the first name who matches to "A" from all A-names to change to class="first".

Then the next name who matches to "B" from all B-names to class="first" and so on to the end of the array.

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp

Comment: Welcome to SO! What have you tried so far? To help us help you, please add a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: hmmm! sorry, I did not get your question. Could you please explain more what do you mean from marking first names that match to A-Z? Does not this mean all?

Comment: @prasad Thank's but if you run the code snippet you got a error.

Answer (score 0):

use with `querySelectorAll('li')`,`Array#forEach` and `Array#includes` using with element

```js
  
var li=document.querySelectorAll('li')
var k = [];
li.forEach(function(a, b) {
var ltr = a.innerHTML.trim().slice(0, 1);
  if (ltr.match(/[A-Za-z]/)) {
    if (!k.includes(ltr)) {
      k.push(ltr);
      a.classList.add('first')
    }
  }
})
```

```css
.first{
color:red;
}
```

```html
<li class="second">Andy</li>
<li class="second">Andrea</li>
<li class="second">Albert</li>
<li class="second">Bernard</li>
<li class="second">Bert</li>
```

Comment: If you click the "Run code snippet" button. li.forEach is not a function